# How to build a yahoo styled navigation bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation

Hi I am looking to build a navigation bar similar to yahoos, however I was unable to find an example. Some of the features I am looking for are a sticky navigation bar, that kind of looks like it pops out of it's place when the user scrolls.

CSS

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
html { overflow-y: scroll; }
body { 
    font: 62.5% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

ul { list-style: none inside; }
p { font-size: 1.2em; line-height: 1.2em; margin-bottom: 1.2em; }
a img { border: none; }

.floatleft { float: left; }
.floatright { float: right; }
.clear { clear: both; }

a { 
    text-decoration: none; 
    outline: none;
    color: #335588;
    }
    a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }


    #top-bar {
        background: #330000; 
        min-height: 60px;
        padding: 0 10px;
        font-size: 1.3em;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    #right-side {
        float: right;
        padding-top: 15px;
        }
    #right-side img {
        border: 1px solid white;
        vertical-align: middle;
        }
    #right-side a {
        color: white;
        border-left: 1px solid white;
        height: 10px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        }
    #right-side a.first {
        border: none;
        padding: 0;
        }

    #left-side {
        float: left;
        padding-top: 15px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        color: white;
        font-size: 20px;
        }


    #sub-menu {
        background: white;
        min-height: 20px;
        padding: 5px 10px 0 10px;
        }
    #sub-menu ul {
        display: block;
        color: #000000;
        }
    #sub-menu ul li {
        height: 18px;
        padding: 5px 10px 0 5px;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 10px;
        color: #000000;
        }
    #sub-menu ul li:hover {
        background: red;
        height: 10px;
        }
    #sub-menu ul li a {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        height: 23px;
        position: relative;
        top: -5px;
        right: -5px;
        padding-right: 3px;
        color: #000000;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        text-decoration: none;
        }

    #sub-menu ul li a span {
        position: relative;
        top: 6px;
        }
    #sub-menu ul li ul {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 29px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 150px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background: white;
        padding: 10px 0 0 0;
        }
    #sub-menu ul li ul li {
        float: none;
        padding: 0; margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        }
    #sub-menu ul li ul li:hover {
        background: none;
        }
    #sub-menu ul li ul li a {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        margin-left: -5px;
        padding: 5px 0 0 10px;
        width: 140px;
        }
    #sub-menu ul li ul li a:hover {
        background: #000000;
        }
```

HTML

```
<div id="top-bar">
    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="TEST" class="floatleft" />  
        <div id="left-side">
            TEST
        </div>

        <div id="right-side">
            <a href="#">Logout</a>          
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="sub-menu">
        <ul>
                       <li></li>
                       <li></li>
                       <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

here is an updated jsfiddle, i got the line to show up but it still wont be sticky jsfiddle.net/cc48t/1549

Comment: You'll have to post what you've tried, and code samples or screenshots of the issues you're having.

Comment: Well anyways the question is off topic, but I am amazed to know that still there are few who loves yahoo stuff..

Comment: Check out: http://jsfiddle.net/cc48t/ that should point you in the right direction.

Comment: here is an updated jsfiddle, i got the line to show up but it still wont be sticky http://jsfiddle.net/cc48t/1549/

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not purely CSS. With jQuery, you can put something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $(this).scrollTop() > 0 ? $('body').css('background', '#f0f') : $('body').css('background', '#0f0');
}).scroll();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Raxpj/)